# Make URLfield display an error instead of just being red, with invalid validator

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have an URL-field, when I enter an invalid URL (without `http`) it just displays a red border around the field like so.

[image: d]

If I click "submit" it does says "enter a valid url". Since some persons does not know, that `http` is required to be "valid" I want to add that as a message below, just like when calling `clean_link` raises an validation error.

How can I do that, apart from removing the validation and add that step in `clean_field` instead?

Comment: I think you are looking for `error_messages` - [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#error-messages)

Comment: They first appear when you click "submit" - this red border appears *before* you click like a "live validator". I try to figure what is causing the red border (say if I want to make it blue), and add some additional text to it

Comment: django form validations will happen only after you click submit, for client-side validation, maybe you can use jquery validation plugin - [link](https://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method). This will validate the fields as soon as you move the cursor to next field.

Comment: @CutePoison That has nothing to do with Django. It is your browser performing some validation. If you want to disable that set the `novalidate` attribute on your form tag like `<form novalidate>`, if you want to modify that you are best to look for some javascript solution (perhaps the one suggested in above comment by Ejaz)

Comment: even adding `novalidate` like `<div class="form-group" novalidate>  {{form.link|as_crispy_field}}  </div> ` still validates it (it seems like)

Comment: @CutePoison not on the `div` tag use the `novalidate` attribute on the **`form`** tag, or as an alternative try setting the `formnovalidate` on the **`input`** tag

Comment: Aaahh. gotcha! The issues is that all the other fields aren't validated now (since they are in the same `<form>` tag. It can't be done for a single input (using the django-notation above) ?

Comment: Here's all the details on [client side form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation) and here specifically for [<input type="url">](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url#validation)